# Alternative ways to show divergence of this series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Suppose that  for $0 \leq r \leq 2^n-1$ and $n \geq 0$, we have $$a_{2^n+r}=(-1)^n \frac{1}{2^n+r}.$$
Then we need to show that the series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = 1-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{8}-\dots-\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{16}+\dots$$ diverges.

The way by which I have done this is to use the following (which can be checked essentially by using an integral test) $$\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{k+1}+\dots + \frac{1}{2k-1} \to \log 2^{+} \ \ \ (\text{as} \ k \to \infty)$$ and so $$\frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^n+1}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1} \to \log 2^{+}.$$ Since these expressions tend to $\log 2$ from above, they always have a value greater than $\log 2$.

Then if we consider the $(1+2+4+\dots+2^m)$th partial sum for some $m \in \mathbb N$, then this differs from the $(1+2+4+\dots+2^m + 2^{m+1})$th partial sum by at least $\log 2$ and hence the $k$th partial sums of the original series do not form a Cauchy sequence, and hence it must diverge.

Are there any alternative, potentially more direct ways, of showing that the series diverges?

Comment: The $2^n$ looks like an application of Cauchy's condensation test could be possible.

Comment: I think what you have is about as direct as you can get (though the explanation is perhaps a bit unclear). As you state, you’re showing that the sequence of partial sums is not a Cauchy sequence and therefore cannot converge. Except for presenting the notation a little more clearly, I think this is as direct as you can get since you’re working with a series with terms that change signs.

Comment: @Clayton What is unclear about the explanation?

Comment: $$\sum_{m\in [2^{2n},2^{2n+1})} a_m \ge 1/2$$